# About Notification for Missed Call in android

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, sip, pjsip

I am using voip sip for calling processing calls when `Push-Notification` received. I want to create top bar notification for missed call . I am already processing calls when `Push-Notification` receives. I already searched lot of things but nothing helped me.

My question is, i'm making calls after receiving `Push-Notification`, so likewise i want to display notification after receiving Push Notification, so for that how do I differentiate for which i am receiving `Push-Notification`.

Comment: @InsaneCat application team working on Api for it.. Didn't get Api....Waiting for it...But Hope your answer is right...thank you...After getting into work if I have any doubts, then I will ask.

Comment: Great!! sure Happy to help you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notification you are receiving it always contains extra information, all you have to do in compare both notification packets and identify the key using which you can differentiate both of notification. If you are not able to find such key ask API developer to provide it.

Answer (score 1):

You can get something unique in notification response for deffrentiate means notifications you are getting extra data please check in notification response or check in voip sip's documentation (if not getting this extra information ask api developer to provide it) using it you can identify whether you are receiving missed call notification or call notification.

Hope this may helps you.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html#DURATION

Call duration == 0, so call was missed