# Not able to clear notification and open fragment from notification

Tags: java, android, android-studio, notifications, fragment

I am trying to clear notification. But it remains there. Not able to open fragment Activity from notification. Below is my code,

```
 @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        int sticky;

        try {
            AndroidLogger.log(5, TAG, "Missed call notification on start");
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH; //Important for heads-up notification
                NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("1", "Call Notification", importance);
                channel.setDescription("Get alert for missed call");
                channel.setShowBadge(true);
                channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
                NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            }
            Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(this, ViewFragment.class);
            notifyIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);


            PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notifyIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "1")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.nexge_logo)
                    .setContentTitle("Missed Call")
                    .setContentText(intent.getStringExtra("Number"))
                    .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);

            Notification buildNotification = mBuilder.build();
            NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            //mNotifyMgr.notify(1, buildNotification);

            startForeground(1,buildNotification);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            AndroidLogger.error(1, TAG, "Exception while starting service", exception);
        }
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
}
```

Anybody help me to solve this. Thanks in Advance.
Below is my another question for which I didn't get a proper answer. Help me with that also
[About Notification for Missed Call in android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59573330/11630822)

Comment: Please join this group [Android & Kotlin Experts](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50272/android-kotlin-experts) and ping me i'll explain there.

Comment: @Ali I didn't have enough reputation to talk in chat

Comment: You have bro you just wait for admin accept your request. You send the joining request?

Comment: Okay forgot about group yet. Your question is if you click on Notification then Fragment not load right?

Comment: @Ali ya thats right and one more thing is not able to clear the notification on the top bar after swiping right

Comment: Okay you have home activity which load fragments?

Comment: @Ali I have mentioned my Fragment class which I want to open in Pending intent

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205579/discussion-between-ali-and-kousalya).

Comment: @Ali yes I have

Answer (score 0):

My solution to a similar issue has been changing PendingIntent Flag to PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
From Android documentation:

> Flag indicating that this PendingIntent can be used only once. For use with getActivity(Context, int, Intent, int), getBroadcast(Context, int, Intent, int), and getService(Context, int, Intent, int).
>
> If set, after send() is called on it, it will be automatically canceled for you and any future attempt to send through it will fail.

and adding notification FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL flag:

`mBuilder.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;`

which should make sure the notification will be removed once used.

**Edit**:
Should call

```
Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
```

first, then

```
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

**Edit2**:
Just noticed that you are using the notification for `startForeground()`. This means that the notification will stay for as long as your Service / Activity is running (this is by default so the user will know that there is a Service / Activity still running).

The notification will stay for as long as your Service / Activity does run as foreground service.

Comment: In my code Im having two more channels...When I open my app, at the time in  the top bar there will be one notification shown like mentioning this app is running now. And that will be gone only when app is closed.. Whether that causes the notification which I have created not to be cleared???

Comment: Basically, yes. Since you mentioned another two channels which are not visible in the code you've posted, I cannot tell you for sure, but in case you will want to show just a one-show notification with some intent attached to it, you have to show it using "mNotifyMgr.notify(1, buildNotification)" instead of "startForeground(1, buildNotification)"

Comment: I have tried using "mNotifyMgr.notify(1, buildNotification)". but nothing changed and I got a exception like RemoteException